# When can uid 1 get an access denied page?

Tags: 6, users, theming

I am having a very strange problem that I can't track down.

We have been working on a custom site for a client now for several months.  Theme is a Zen subtheme.

I can't remember the last time I tried to access it, but I am getting an "access denied" when I try to view /admin/build/themes/settings/mysubtheme, even as uid 1.  It is getting logged this way, too, so I think it really is an access denied.  I can access this page for Zen, Rootcandy, and other enabled themes.

I have done all of the usual tricks for attempting to fix this (run cron, clear cache, rebuild node perms, assign all perms to my superuser role, etc) without luck.

A `theme-settings.php` exists for the theme and all of the hooks are named properly for the theme.

How is this possible since [user_access](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_access/6) returns `TRUE` when `uid==1`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After trying to fix this for an hour, I tumbled on the solution right after I posted this.  Apparently, it is possible to set a theme as "default" but not have it "enabled", and have a site function normally.  Enabling the theme fixes the problem.

Comment: No need to delete, this could be a solution for someone else in the future.  Just once the allotted time has passed, mark your answer accepted

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't want to give the appearance that I posted a question just so I could answer it myself.

Comment: It is perfectly valid to answer your own questions if you are able to find the solution. Maybe someone else will have the same problem at some point and find this question through a search engine. This is a Q&A database, not a one-off support facility :)

Comment: I had this issue where I couldn't clear the cache from the UI. Your answer is what I had wrong. Thanks.